Monitoring local DNS server
I use AdGuard on Raspberry Pi at home for DNS, and it has been working well for several years.
In the past few weeks, Firefox occasionally displays a "page not found" error.
This seems to occur more frequently with unfamiliar domains, leading me to suspect a DNS related problem. Since the Raspberry Pi is aging and running off a USB stick, I'm considering replacing the Pi. However, I would like to gather quantitative data on the frequency of DNS failures before making any changes.
Is there  a Linux program that can request a DNS record of a domain, every 5 minutes without utilizing the cache?
Ideally, this program would track and display the number of failures and successes, as well as the timing of each attempt.
I am thinking dig @[LOCAL-DNS-IP] example.com or something but every 5 minutes with a report that shows the failures.

Both dig and nslookup will do this. That's what they are there for; conversely host will use the local DNS cache. But do check what server (or explicitly set) the DNS server; systemd-resolved (probably running on your local machine) behaves like a caching DNS server.
Scheduling and maintaining stats is what monitoring systems do. There are a lots of good free ones to choose from but the effort in setting this up would be a lot more than an occasional adhoc analysis of the output of a cron job.
